# Where do I find the windows license key on a Dell XPS without windows currently installed?

Tags: windows, dell-xps

I have a recent Dell XPS and I installed Linux on it. I now wish to install Windows inside a VM but there is no license key anywhere on the laptop or in the box. All of the answers I can see say its embedded in the bios but I don't see any way the Windows in a VM could access this. Is there any way to get the windows key without windows currently installed?

Comment: Windows keys on all recent OEM machines, which your machine is, license is stored in the ACPI table.  It is not necessary to retrieve this information in order to install and activate WIndows 10.

Comment: Are OSs in a VM able to access this table?